# Spring Boot SSL could not get any response

Tags: ssl, https, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using Spring Boot generated with JHipster. I generated keystore using Java's keytool app. My .yml file looks like :

```
server:
    port: 9090
    ssl:
        enabled: true
        key-store: myKeystore.p12
        key-store-password: ******
        key-store-provider: SunJSSE
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-alias: tomcat
        protocol: TLS
```

When I set enabled to false, server works on HTTP protocol, when I enable it getting no response from server for any endpoint using HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Did you put port in URL in https too? Like https://localhost:9090

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried https://localhost:9090/ and http://localhost:9090/.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you used a certificate that is not trusted by a CA.
If you test with postman or any request simulator it will return 0Bytes.
If you test with a browser it will tell you that you must trust manually the certificate.